# Dynamically Updating a Programmatically Created Link (e.g. – Blob)

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, blob, immutability

I'm currently creating an ObjectURL from a Blob, derived from a growing array of incoming, live-streamed media chunks:

```
URL ⬅ Blob ⬅ some processing ⬅ dynamic array ⬅ growing list of MP4 chunks
```

Problem being, I require a **single** URL to work with this array, and cannot access a remote server to acquire it. Using Blobs works to an extent, but since they are immutable and each URL returned from the createObjectURL routine is unique – I'm at a loss as to how to do this. Essentially, as my array grows, it needs to be accessible from the programmatically-derived 'http://example.com/asdfasdf' address.

Is there another method to generate a more consistent, consumable outlet? I say 'consumable' as my testing criteria states that the should be compatible with the native HTML5 video element.